# How do you find rosdep definition location?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y
```

The outout is:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:  spin_database: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [lamp]
```

My understanding from reading this (https://answers.ros.org/question/320734/cannot-locate-rosdep-definition/) is that rosdep looked for a package that is named lamp.

The node spin_database is a node that I have created, but I am not aware of where rosdep is looking for this definition.

Where can I find the location of these dependencies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350193/how-do-you-find-rosdep-definition-location?/) by [marcp17](https://answers.ros.org/users/52300/marcp17/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rosdep` DB is here: [ros/rosdistro/rosdep](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/93ba98517ac260add8670a249c3e47aee7ac5e49/rosdep), in most cases you'll want to look at `base.yaml`.

> My understanding from reading this (https://answers.ros.org/question/320734/cannot-locate-rosdep-definition/) is that rosdep looked for a package that is named lamp.

No, not quite. `rosdep` tries to lookup the *key* `lamp` in the database. Note the difference: a key has to be resolved to a package name. It's not a package name itself, *unless* it's the name of a ROS package. But then you would most likely get a different error.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcp17](https://answers.ros.org/users/52300/marcp17/) on 2020-04-22**:
Ahh ok, I see. Do you know where and why it is looking for the key "lamp"?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-22**:
Most likely because you've listed it as a `build` or `exec` depend in your `package.xml`, or it's listed in one of the other packages in the workspace.

**Comment by [marcp17](https://answers.ros.org/users/52300/marcp17/) on 2020-04-22**:
It is, thank you!